# Loading "Font Awesome" very slow on Drupal and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, drupal-8

I'm hosting the "Font Awesome" fonts locally on my "Drupal 8" site with the "Bootstrap" theme.

I use the SVG version for my site.

Here is my `bootstrap_subtheme_front_office.libraries.yml` file :

```
bootstrap:
  version: 3.4.1
  js:
    bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      ../../contrib/bootstrap/css/3.4.1/overrides-cosmo.min.css: {}
fontawesome:
  version: 5.7.2
  header: true
  js:
    fonts/fontawesome/js/all.min.js: {}
bootstrap-toggle:
  version: 2.2.0
  js:
    js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css: {}
global:
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/back-to-top.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Here is my `bootstrap_subtheme_front_office.info.yml` file :

```
name: Bootstrap Sub-Theme Front Office
type: theme
description: 'Uses the Bootstrap framework LESS source files and must be compiled (not for beginners).'
core: 8.x
base theme: bootstrap
libraries:
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/bootstrap
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/fontawesome
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/bootstrap-toggle
  - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/global
regions:
  navigation_collapsible_first: 'Navigation (Collapsible first)'
  navigation_menu_first: 'Navigation (Menu first)'
  navigation_notification_first: 'Navigation (Notification first)'
  navigation_logo: 'Navigation (Logo)'
  navigation_notification_second: 'Navigation (Notification second)'
  navigation_menu_second: 'Navigation (Menu second)'
  navigation_collapsible_second: 'Navigation (Collapsible second)'
  breadcrumb: 'Breadcrumb'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'
```

When I test the display of my site on my smartphone, it works correctly :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iELrf.jpg)

But some of my visitors, we have problems with the loading of "Font Awesome". The pilice does not load, I have the impression that the internet browser tries to load the police and that he gives up after a delay :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR103.jpg)

I use a lot of "Font Awesome" fonts on my site (for navigation, menus, ...). How to correct this problem ?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.s1biose.com%2Ffr%2Farticle%2Fla-spiruline-une-micro-algue-dans-nos-assiettes&tab=desktop

Comment: Most page speed bottlenecks should first be analyzed here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ that should give you a good idea on where to start. I'm just browsing Q's so don't expect me to answer much more, but optimizing font awesome load/ reduce fontawesome load yields results in searching

Comment: @StephenJ I updated my question